# How to Rollback Asp.Net Membership Configuration(Tables&Procedures)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm developing a project that works on remote server database tables. But there were no membership, only one admin panel with 1 admin user. So I tried to use Asp.Net membership for this, but when I did that according to tutorials(on C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\aspnet_regsql.exe"), I guess there was a conflict so my project didn't work. I found "Windows authentication" line in my web.config, commented out, fixed it.

Then I decided to use a master password inside the code, with text boxes. This is really simple application, no high-level security needed. So I did it so. But when I opened the database, I realized that Asp.Net created its own tables and stored procedures. Now I want to rollback my Asp.Net (Membership) configuration. I can manually delete the tables and procedures but I fear of doing something wrong. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run aspnet_regsql from .NET command prompt and it will start a wizard. You can either configure or remove the tables.. The wizard gives you option for both.. Select the one you need and your tables etc will be deleted from the database...

Comment: Don't delete them manually as there may always be some elements that you may forget to delete... The wizard is a good option...

Comment: Argh... That was a silly question. Never thought it can take what it did back. That's not what Windows usually does :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using asp.net membership, then it will do no harm to manually delete them.